# Shell scripts and the md5/md5sum command: need to decide when to use which one

Tags: shell, scripting

First time poster, here, so go easy on me. :)

Pretty sure nobody's yet asked this in researching this question.

Short version: How can I tell a shell script to use one command versus the other, depending on which box I run the shell script on? Example: on Box 1, I want to run `md5 file.txt`. On Box 3, I want to run `md5sum file.txt`. I'm thining it's an IF command where if the output of `md5` is a failure, use `md5sum` instead. Just don't know how to check and see whether the output of `md5` is a failure or not

---

Long version: I have 3 boxes that I work with. Box 1 and 3 are the receivers of a file from Box 2, and they receive the file when I invoke a script on box 1/3 as follows: `ftpget.sh file.txt`

I have a shell script that does an FTP GET and grabs a file from Box 2. It then does an md5 on the source file from Box 2 and the destination file, which'll be on Box 1 or 3, depending on which one I executed the script from. The hashes must match, of course.

The problem is this: The code is written to use `md5`, and while Box 1 uses md5, Box 3 uses `md5sum`. So when I execute the script from Box 1, it works great. When I execute the script from Box 3, it fails because Box 3 uses md5sum, not md5.

So I was thinking: what's the best way to handle this? I can't install anything since I'm not an admin, and the people who manage the machine probably won't do it for me anyway. Could I just create an alias in my .profile which goes something like: `alias md5="md5sum"`? That way, when the script runs on Box 3, it'll execute `md5 file.txt` but the system will really execute `md5sum file.txt` since I created the alias.

Thoughts? Better ideas? :)

Comment: The alias sounds like a great idea to me.

Comment: What do you mean you "can't install"?  If you have write permission in your home directory and are able to prepend to your PATH, then you can install the programs you need in $HOME/$(uname -m)/bin

Comment: What I mean is that while I do have write permission to my home directory, that machine is not connected to the Internet; so I can't wget anything and since I'm accessing it through PuTTY, I can't--at least not to my knowledge--transfer any files to my home directory that didn't originate on that machine or another machine connected to it. All these machines are on a private network disconnected from the Internet, so my hands are tied as far as what I am able to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what shell you're using. This is for bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
md5=$(which md5)
if [ ! "${md5}" ] ; then
  md5=$(which md5sum)
  if [ ! "${md5}" ] ; then
    echo "neither md5 nor md5sum found"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
${md5} $0
```

Comment: You might want to do md5=$(which md5 2> /dev/null) to suppress spurious errors.  (Some implementations of which are extremely verbose.)

Comment: When I execute this script I get the following: `findmd5.sh: syntax error at line 2: 'md5=$' unexpected` that first tick before md5 is actually a backtick but keeping it there messes up the code formatting here. Sorry for being such a n00b, but we all have to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions, as is often the case. Perhaps the following script, called somesum(1) would suffice ...

```
#!/bin/sh
# ident "@(#)somesum.sh: Find a command to do a checksum of a file"
################################################################################
export CMD
CMD=''
# if can find the command in the search path and CMD is not set,
# set CMD to the command name ...
[ "$CMD" = '' -a -f "`which md5    2>/dev/null`" ]  && CMD=md5
[ "$CMD" = '' -a -f "`which md5sum  2>/dev/null`" ]  && CMD=md5sum
################################################################################
# if command was found execute it else complain could not find desired commands
if [ "$CMD" != '' ]
then
   $CMD $*
else
   echo could not find md5sum or md5 1>&2
fi
exit
```

Or installing the preferred command on the other platforms in your own search path; 
or using the hostname(1) command to figure out which platform you are on. I am assuming
you are on a platform that has the Bash shell (or ksh/pdksh/bash/...) in the example.