# How do I detect a failed state on multiple files when running md5sum on multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I use:

```
md5sum * > checklist.chk # Generates a list of checksums and files.
```

and use:

```
md5sum -c checklist.chk   # runs through the list to check them
```

How can I automate a PASS or FAIL state? I basically want to get a notification if something on my app changes. Whether by hacker or unauthorized change by a developer. I want to write a script that will notify of any changes to my code.

I found a few scripts online but they only appear to work for single files, I have been unable to adapt the script to work for multiple files with pass or fail states.

```
if [ "$(md5sum < File.name)" = "24f4ce42e0bc39ddf7b7e879a  -" ]
then
  echo Pass
else
  echo Fail
fi
```

Reference:

[Shell scripts and the md5/md5sum command: need to decide when to use which one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115504/shell-scripts-and-the-md5-md5sum-command-need-to-decide-when-to-use-which-one)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290240/md5sum-check-no-file

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
for f in $(awk '{printf"%s ", $2}' checklist.chk); do
    md5sum=$(grep $f checklist.chk | awk '{print $1}')
    if [[ "$(md5sum < $f)" = "$md5sum  -" ]]; then 
        echo Pass
    else
        echo Fail
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your checksums directly in the script. Then just run the `md5sum -c`.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_stored_checksums() {
grep -P '^[0-9a-f]{32}  .' <<-'EOF'
#########################################################
# Stored checksums in the script itself
# the output from the md5sum for the files you want guard
5e3f61b243679426d7f74c22b863438b  Workbook1.xls
777a161c82fe0c810e00560411fb076e  Workbook1.xlsx

# empty lines and comments - theyre simply ignored
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  abc def.xxx

# this very important file
809f911bcde79d6d0f6dc8801d367bb5  jj.xxx
#########################################################
EOF
}

#MAIN
cd /where/the/files/are

#run the md5sum in the check-mode
result=$( md5sum -c <(get_stored_checksums) )
if (( $? ))
then
    #found some problems
    echo "$result"
    #mail -s "PROBLEM" security.manager@example.com <<<"$result"
#else
#   echo "all OK"
fi
```

If something is wrong, you will see something like:

```
Workbook1.xls: OK
Workbook1.xlsx: OK
abc def.xxx: FAILED
jj.xxx: OK
md5sum: WARNING: 1 of 4 computed checksums did NOT match
```

Of course, you can change the `get_stored_checksums` function to anything other, like:

```
get_stored_checksums() {
    curl -s 'http://integrityserver.example.com/mytoken'
}
```

and you will fetch the guarded checksums from the remote server...